custom seuential layer which can iterate over each value in the input
I would like to make a custom layer which takes an image (2D) and does some math to each pixel and then passes this to the next layer.
I have below some psudo code which tries to implement this. How can I implement something like this using tensorflow?
class MyLayer(Layer):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  def call(self, inputs):
    x_dim, y_dim = inputs.shape  #assume the incoming layer was reshaped to be a 2D image

# Initialize output matrix with zeros
output_matrix = tf.zeros((x_dim, y_dim))
# Iterate through zx, and y dimensions, note this will NOT work
    for x in tf.range(x_dim):
        for y in tf.range(y_dim):
          math = x*y
          output_matrix[x,y] += math
return output_matrix

When I attempt something like the above, I get error messages that I cannot iterate over a tensor.

Indeed TensorFlow's tensor can't be iterated over in Python sequential loops directly which breaks its computational graph based execution even in eager mode because they are symbolic representations optimized for devices like GPUs parallel computation. Instead, you need to leverage TensorFlow's vectorized operations to apply your intended element-wise multiplication which builds a single graph node for the multiplication operation applied in parallel across all tensor elements using optimized low-level libraries like XLA (Accelerated Linear Algebra) or cuDNN (for NVIDIA GPUs). You could try code like below to achieve same.
import tensorflow as tf

x_grid = tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4]], dtype=tf.float32)
y_grid = tf.constant([[5, 6], [7, 8]], dtype=tf.float32)

result = x_grid * y_grid  # Vectorized multiplication
print(result)

Output:
tf.Tensor(
[[ 5. 12.]
 [21. 32.]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32)


Programming questions, including questions like "How can I implement this in TensorFlow?", are off-topic here. We shouldn't answer them, as this encourages people. We should instead vote to close them as off-topic. More info about what is or not on-topic here: https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
